# Some error persists in my ANN and I don't know why it is coming in the first place. Somebody please explain with code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Error existing in model.evaluate() as ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to #have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 28, 28)

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28)
X_train.shape

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784, )))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784, )))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5)

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

print("The accuracy of the Artificial Neural Network is: {}".format(test_accuracy))
print("Loss calculation of ANN is: {}".format(test_loss))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28)
```

You reshaped the training set for the right shape, but you did not do the same for the test set, you need to do:

```
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 28*28)
```

Comment: Thanks Matias. You've been helpful.